# counter increase each time loads the function

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new into javascript , but I am trying to create a counter , but when I setup my counter . it looks gives me the same value , but I want first round `1 then 2 then 3 to n-1`

```
function timer(){
    var contactsNum = 0;
    contactsNum++;
    console.log(contactsNum)
}


(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
   timer()
    loop()
  }, 9000);
}());
```

Comment: Move `var contactsNum = 0;` out of your function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because variable `contactsNum` is local to the function timer, and every subsequent call of function `timer` will initialize the value 0. If you want to keep track of the value you can use closure.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
function timer(){
    var contactsNum = 0;
    contactsNum++;
    console.log(contactsNum)
}
```

You are defining and assigning a variable in `timer`. That means, everytime `timer` gets called, `contactsNum` gets set to 0.

You need to put it outside of the function like:

```
let contactsNum = 0;
function timer() {  
    contactsNum++;
    console.log(contactsNum)
}
```